# Replicate a sequence when a condition is met

Tags: r, sequence, replicate

To generate the output below, I am using the following code:

safe.ifelse <- function(cond, yes, no) structure(ifelse(cond, yes, no), class = class(yes))

library(lubridate)

df <- data.frame(i_date=mdy("9/1/2011") + months(seq(0,31)), t_date=mdy("2/1/2012")) 
r <- seq(1:nrow(df))

r <- (r - which(df$i_date == df$t_date)) %/% 12

df$r_date <- as.Date(safe.ifelse(r<0, df$i_date, df$t_date + years(r)), origin = "1970-01-01")

For good reason, I get an error if I set the t_date to be beyond the biggest i_date. Does anyone know a way to avoid this error? So instead of finding where the i_date and t_date match, replicating the t_date 12 times and adding a year, replicating again 12 times etc, I would just cascade the i_date the entire way to the end of the r_date where all three columns of the data frame have the same length. So in the case I am referring to, the i_date would match the t_date if the t_date is > max(i_date) otherwise we would do what we see below. Thanks!

```
i_date       t_date      r_date
9/1/2011    2/1/2012    9/1/2011
10/1/2011   2/1/2012    10/1/2011
11/1/2011   2/1/2012    11/1/2011
12/1/2011   2/1/2012    12/1/2011
1/1/2012    2/1/2012    1/1/2012
2/1/2012    2/1/2012    2/1/2012
3/1/2012    2/1/2012    2/1/2012
4/1/2012    2/1/2012    2/1/2012
5/1/2012    2/1/2012    2/1/2012
6/1/2012    2/1/2012    2/1/2012
7/1/2012    2/1/2012    2/1/2012
8/1/2012    2/1/2012    2/1/2012
9/1/2012    2/1/2012    2/1/2012
10/1/2012   2/1/2012    2/1/2012
11/1/2012   2/1/2012    2/1/2012
12/1/2012   2/1/2012    2/1/2012
1/1/2013    2/1/2012    2/1/2012
2/1/2013    2/1/2012    2/1/2013
3/1/2013    2/1/2012    2/1/2013
4/1/2013    2/1/2012    2/1/2013
5/1/2013    2/1/2012    2/1/2013
6/1/2013    2/1/2012    2/1/2013
7/1/2013    2/1/2012    2/1/2013
8/1/2013    2/1/2012    2/1/2013
9/1/2013    2/1/2012    2/1/2013
10/1/2013   2/1/2012    2/1/2013
11/1/2013   2/1/2012    2/1/2013
12/1/2013   2/1/2012    2/1/2013
1/1/2014    2/1/2012    2/1/2013
2/1/2014    2/1/2012    2/1/2014
3/1/2014    2/1/2012    2/1/2014
4/1/2014    2/1/2012    2/1/2014
```

Comment: It's nice to have the desired output, but what was the input?

Comment: The input is the first two columns.

Comment: Ideally I would use the first 2 columns in my data frame to generate the 3rd column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for ordered data where the `i_date` increments in steps of one month as in data above. I'll use `lubridate` package to make it easier to manipulate the dates.

I replicate your data above as a dataframe `df`.

```
library(lubridate)
td <- mdy("2/1/2012")
df <- data.frame(i_date=mdy("9/1/2011") + months(seq(0,31)),
                 t_date=td)
```

I create temporary index in variable `r` to indicate how many years (in essence 12 months) to add. Then simply add `r` number of years to t_date from the point where `r` is not negative (i.e. `i_date` is no longer smaller than `t_date`). Set `r` to negative if `t_date` is not in the range of `i_date`.

```
if (td %in% df$i_date) {
  r <- (seq(1:nrow(df)) - which(df$i_date == df$t_date)) %/% 12
} else { r <- rep(-1, nrow(df)) }
df$r_date <- as.POSIXct(ifelse(r<0, df$i_date,
                                    df$t_date + years(r)), origin = "1970-01-01")
```

My result below.

```
       i_date     t_date              r_date
1  2011-09-01 2012-02-01 2011-09-01 08:00:00
2  2011-10-01 2012-02-01 2011-10-01 08:00:00
3  2011-11-01 2012-02-01 2011-11-01 08:00:00
4  2011-12-01 2012-02-01 2011-12-01 08:00:00
5  2012-01-01 2012-02-01 2012-01-01 08:00:00
6  2012-02-01 2012-02-01 2012-02-01 08:00:00
7  2012-03-01 2012-02-01 2012-02-01 08:00:00
8  2012-04-01 2012-02-01 2012-02-01 08:00:00
9  2012-05-01 2012-02-01 2012-02-01 08:00:00
10 2012-06-01 2012-02-01 2012-02-01 08:00:00
11 2012-07-01 2012-02-01 2012-02-01 08:00:00
12 2012-08-01 2012-02-01 2012-02-01 08:00:00
13 2012-09-01 2012-02-01 2012-02-01 08:00:00
14 2012-10-01 2012-02-01 2012-02-01 08:00:00
15 2012-11-01 2012-02-01 2012-02-01 08:00:00
16 2012-12-01 2012-02-01 2012-02-01 08:00:00
17 2013-01-01 2012-02-01 2012-02-01 08:00:00
18 2013-02-01 2012-02-01 2013-02-01 08:00:00
19 2013-03-01 2012-02-01 2013-02-01 08:00:00
20 2013-04-01 2012-02-01 2013-02-01 08:00:00
21 2013-05-01 2012-02-01 2013-02-01 08:00:00
22 2013-06-01 2012-02-01 2013-02-01 08:00:00
23 2013-07-01 2012-02-01 2013-02-01 08:00:00
24 2013-08-01 2012-02-01 2013-02-01 08:00:00
25 2013-09-01 2012-02-01 2013-02-01 08:00:00
26 2013-10-01 2012-02-01 2013-02-01 08:00:00
27 2013-11-01 2012-02-01 2013-02-01 08:00:00
28 2013-12-01 2012-02-01 2013-02-01 08:00:00
29 2014-01-01 2012-02-01 2013-02-01 08:00:00
30 2014-02-01 2012-02-01 2014-02-01 08:00:00
31 2014-03-01 2012-02-01 2014-02-01 08:00:00
32 2014-04-01 2012-02-01 2014-02-01 08:00:00
```

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I wanted, however, when I attempt to use your code, I get the following messages:

Error: object 'r' not found after the line where you have r <- (r - which(df$i_date == df$t_date)) %/% 12

Comment: I keep trying to initialize r in the above code with different values and I can't seem to get anything to cascade down in the manner than you have in your output.

Comment: Apologies I missed out one line. r starting value should be the sequence of number of rows:

    r <- seq(1:nrow(df))

I've edited my answer above, see if it works now.

Comment: I will try it as soon as I get home thank you so much for your help I greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Running that code I am getting the last day of each month like:

2011-08-31 19:00:00
2011-09-30 19:00:00
etc

Comment: I am now using this code and it seems to be working: 
safe.ifelse <- function(cond, yes, no) structure(ifelse(cond, yes, no), class = class(yes)) 
library(lubridate) 
df <- data.frame(i_date=mdy("9/1/2011") + months(seq(0,31)), t_date=mdy("2/1/2012")) 
r <- seq(1:nrow(df)) 
r <- (r - which(df$i_date == df$t_date)) %/% 12 
df$r_date <- as.Date(safe.ifelse(r<0, df$i_date, df$t_date + years(r)), origin = "1970-01-01")

Comment: One minor annoyance, when the i_rate never reaches the t_date, I am getting an error which makes sense because r is empty. Is there an easy way around that?

Comment: It was initially meant to be a a quick answer based on your sample data. Once you want to put error checking it gets a bit complicated.

When it never reaches, it can be because `t_date` is smaller than smallest `i_date`, bigger than biggest `i_date`, in-between `i_date`. Which one to cover, or all?

Also, can we assume that `t_date` is always the same, as in your example above? It will be different error-checking if we were to cater for differing `t_date`. On the other hand, if `t_date` is always the same, I'd think it better to keep `t_date` as a constant outside the table / dataframe.

Comment: Based on my data t_date can never be smaller than the min of i_date but can be bigger than the max of i_date

Comment: I will assume `t_date` value is a constant then, that I will initially store in `td`.

    td <- mdy("2/1/2012")
    df <- data.frame(i_date=mdy("9/1/2011") + months(seq(0,31)),
                 t_date=td)
    if (td %in% df$i_date) {
      r <- (seq(1:nrow(df)) - which(df$i_date == df$t_date)) %/% 12
    } else { r <- rep(-1, nrow(df)) }
    df$r_date <- as.POSIXct(ifelse(r<0, df$i_date, df$t_date + years(r)), origin = "1970-01-01")

I hope this is sufficient to close this question.

Comment: Great! can you accept it as the answer for the question then?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think using `rep` with `ifelse` makes a lot of sense because `ifelse` operates on each row. I assume ones you start replacing, you will continue to do so for the rest of the data.frame. Assuming your data.frame above is called `x` and that the first two columns are proper date classes, then i might do

```
ww <- seq_along(x$i_date)-which(x$i_date == x$t_date)
```

to identify each row by it's offset from where the values are equal. Then we can add years to the pivot date to calculate the values for the rest of the rows

```
pvdate <- as.Date(
    paste(as.numeric(strftime(x$t_date[ww==0], "%Y"))+0:max(floor(ww/12)), 
    strftime(x$t_date[ww==0], "%m-%d"), sep="-")
)
```

That's a bit of messy date arithmetic, but it gets the job done. Now i just combine the unreplaced rows with the replaced ones

```
x$r_date<-c(x$i_date[ww<=0], rep(pvdate, table(floor(ww[ww>0]/12))))
```

It's not exactly elegant, but perhaps someone will have a better solution.